# Call data attribute inside function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have some dropdown list like this :

```
<select name="qty" class="mb10" onchange="test()" data-plan-type="offer" data-plan-id="7395" data-plan-day="2210009">
    <option value="0">0 rooms</option>
    <option value="1">1 rooms</option>
    <option value="2">2 rooms</option>
    <option value="3">3 rooms</option>
    <option value="4">4 rooms</option>
</select>
```

And this is my function which called with `onchange` event :

```
function test()
{
    var this_plan_type = $(this).data('plan-type');
    var this_plan_id = $(this).data('plan-id');
    var this_plan_day = $(this).data('plan-day');

    alert(this_plan_type);
}
```

The problem is with `onchange` event I cannot call **data attribute** in my `<select>`. How could I call that data attribute inside function ?

Comment: You need to pass object of element as parameter

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Do you have another way to do that ?

Comment: Use jquery to bind change event

Comment: How could I do that ? Maybe you have some example ? @MilindAnantwar

Comment: Put id to the select and use $('#selectQTY').data('plan-type');

Comment: @Antonio: posted the answer with all possible solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value,

```
<select name="qty" class="mb10" onchange="test.bind(this)()" data-plan-type="offer" data-plan-id="7395" data-plan-day="2210009">
</select>
```

```js
function test() {
  var this_plan_type = $(this).data('plan-type');
  var this_plan_id = $(this).data('plan-id');
  var this_plan_day = $(this).data('plan-day');
  console.clear();
  console.log(this_plan_type, this_plan_id, this_plan_day);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="qty" class="mb10" onchange="test.bind(this)()" data-plan-type="offer" data-plan-id="7395" data-plan-day="2210009">
    <option value="0">0 rooms</option>
    <option value="1">1 rooms</option>
    <option value="2">2 rooms</option>
    <option value="3">3 rooms</option>
    <option value="4">4 rooms</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow. Interesting...wasn't  aware of this sytax :)

Comment: It's working and @MilindAnantwar answer is working too. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because keyword `this` do not refers to select elements context, it is refering to document instead.

You can

1) either pass object of clicked element as argument in function.

and in js:

```
function test($selectElement)
{
var this_plan_type = $selectElement.data('plan-type');
var this_plan_id = $selectElement.data('plan-id');
var this_plan_day = $selectElement.data('plan-day');

alert(this_plan_type);
}
```

2) get element by selector in test method:

```
 function test()
{
var $selectElement = $("select.mb10")
var this_plan_type = $selectElement.data('plan-type');
var this_plan_id =  $selectElement.data('plan-id');
var this_plan_day = $selectElement.data('plan-day');

alert(this_plan_type);
}
```

3) Use jquery to attach event to select element:

```
$(".mb10").change(function(){
   var $selectElement = $(this);
   var this_plan_type =$selectElement.data('plan-type');
   var this_plan_id = $selectElement.data('plan-id');
   var this_plan_day = $selectElement.data('plan-day');
   alert(this_plan_type);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `<select>` as an argument to `test()` and use that instead of `this` (which is bound to the `window` object in your case).

But honestly, you shouldn't use the `onchange` attribute at all. jQuery's [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) method should absolutely do the work, even in IE11.

```js
function test(mySelect)
{
    var this_plan_type = $(mySelect).data('plan-type');
    var this_plan_id = $(mySelect).data('plan-id');
    var this_plan_day = $(mySelect).data('plan-day');

    alert(this_plan_type);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="qty" class="mb10" onchange="test(this)" data-plan-type="offer" data-plan-id="7395" data-plan-day="2210009">
    <option value="0">0 rooms</option>
    <option value="1">1 rooms</option>
    <option value="2">2 rooms</option>
    <option value="3">3 rooms</option>
    <option value="4">4 rooms</option>
</select>
```